# RBF neural networks

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I would like to apply RBF neural networks to teach my system.
I have a system with an input:

```
|    1    2    3    4    5    6 ...   32 |    33 |
| 1000 0001 0010 0100 1000 1000 ... 0100 | 0 0 1 |
```

You have to read this without the "|" character. I just wanted you to see that the last three elements in the input are staying together. The result have to be a number between 1-32, which has the value "1000" in the input. In my training set I will always have a result for an array of this kind. What kind of functions can I use for the teaching algorithm? Can you point me please to the right way?

If you can't understand my description please don't hesitate to ask about it. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RBF network for this seems like a weird solution. But if you have your heart set on it:
(it is entirely possible that I totally misunderstood the problem you want to solve).

You might want to put it in terms of classification and train 32 binary classifiers that determine if the "1000" is at each of the 32 entries. Or more in "neural network" terms have 32*4 entries and 32 ouputs.

One efficent way to train an RBF network is to use an SVM with an RBF kernel. One good implementation of this is [LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/).